# How to access RackSpace phpmyadmin

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm working in windows environment, But I want to access Linux Magento directory(`htdocs`) as well database(`phpmyadmin`) which is hosted in RackSpace.

Could you please instruct me the steps to achieve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about RackSpace. Please contact RackSpace for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rackspace don't have phpnyadmin , you have to access it via SSH or MySQL clients like workbench or sqlyog

Comment: Could you please let me know more about how to access MySQL client through workbench or sqlyog?

Comment: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/connect-to-a-cloud-database-with-a-fqdn-address-via-mysql-workbench

Comment: Thank you so much.. you are saved lot of time and help me out from this problem.